Autodesk APS error Deprecated Service, please contact aps.help@autodesk.com
Error while running asp.autodesk viewer to view revit file on viewer.
Get Token Failed! status = 401 ; message = {"developerMessage":"Deprecated Service, please contact aps.help@autodesk.com to learn more on migrating to Oauth v2.","moreInfo":"
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/developers_guide/error_handling/","errorCode":"AUTH-666"}
i am using trail version for testing purpose

You need to migrate to OAuth v2: 
https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/migration-guide-oauth2-v1-v2
It's a very simple process, but contact us if you cannot migrate to v2 right now:  
https://aps.autodesk.com/contact-support
